# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys' when attempting to use pandas from_records to create dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently trying to convert a `list` of `dict` that has a `value` in a `key:value` pair set as a `list` of `str`. When I go to convert it into a `dataframe` using `pd.DataFram.from_records(conversion_dict)` I get the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'`. I discovered that this was because one of the `key:value` pairs in my `list` of `dict` is a `list` of multiple `str`. So when I call it using the index, such as when using `pd.DataFrame.from_records(conversion_dict[0])` it will create **N** number of entries into the `dataframe` where **N** is the number of individual `str` in the `value` of the `key:value`pair.

My code:

```
def movie_info(list_id):
    movie = tmdb.Movies(list_id).info()
    time.sleep(.15)
    movie_dict = {
        'title': movie['original_title'],
        'release_date': movie['release_date'],
        'runtime': movie['runtime'],
        'genres': [genre.get('name') for genre in movie['genres']],
        'budget': movie['budget'],
        'revenue': movie['revenue']
    }
    
    return movie_dict
```

The `genres` line creates a `list` of the `genres`. When I try to store it in the `DataFrame` I get the aforementioned error.

[image]

[image]

So, what I am wondering is how to convert this `list` into a `dataframe` where the `value` in question is stored as a `list` in the `dataframe`, instead of trying to create multiple rows in the `dataframe`.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, First of all the spelling of word, DataFrame is incorrect in your code. Also please share a sample of input and expected output!

Comment: @PRIN Done! Sorry, I was trying to be succinct with the description because I wasn't sure if my code would do it justice to explain the actual issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing this line:

```
'genres': [[genre.get('name') for genre in movie['genres']]],
```

Note the extra `[]` added

Comment: @Farid_Jafri does this work because it is casting the `list` comprehension as a `list`?

Comment: It has to do with how DataFrame object is created:`pd.DataFrame({'Yes': [50, 21], 'No': [131, 2]})`. This code will create 2 rows but if you add extra [] to both values of Yes and No, it will be counted as a single object